# Kde does not work properly when changing the subsetting in a dataframe in R, to do a 95% kernel

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am currently working with a Cetacean sights database, where each observation has its coordenates. I want to do a 95% kernel to define the area where 95% of observations occur. When I do it subsetting the data by months, it works fine.

```
Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001_2018 <- read_excel("C:/Users/ESTIMADO 
USUARIO/Desktop/AZORES/Trabajo/Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001-2018.xlsx", 
                                       sheet = "Sheet1")

Sights <- as.data.frame(Avistamientos_cetaceos_2001_2018)
SightsMay <- Sights[Sights$month == 5,]

SightsCoorMay <- cbind(SightsMay$longitude, SightsMay$latitude)

SightsCoorMay <- as.data.frame(SightsCoorMay)

kd2May <- ks::kde(SightsCoorMay, compute.cont=TRUE)


contour_95May <- with(kd2May, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                   z=estimate, levels=cont["5%"])[[1]])

contour_95dfMay <- data.frame(contour_95May)

ggplot(data=SightsCoorMay, aes(V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(color="red") +
  geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_95May_DF) +
  theme_bw()
```

[95% kernel of the observations. You can see its accurate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVKGf.png)

Here you can see how it works fine when I subset the data by month, but when I do it by year, the result is quite different.

```
Sights01 <- Sights[Sights$year == 2001,]
SightsCoor01 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Sights01$longitude, Sights01$latitude))
kd201 <- ks::kde(SightsCoor01, compute.cont=TRUE)

contour_9501 <- with(kd201, contourLines(x=eval.points[[1]], y=eval.points[[2]],
                                   z=estimate, levels=cont["95%"])[[1]])

contour_95df01 <- data.frame(contour_9501)

ggplot(data=SightsCoor01, aes(V1, V2)) +
  geom_point(color="red") +
  geom_path(aes(x, y), data=contour_9501_DF) +
  theme_bw()
```

[You can see hot the supposed 95% area is just a tiny part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v51Wm.png)

I have checked everything, the type of file the coordinates, and I cant find a reasonable explanation, so any help would be really useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the `SightsCoor01` object come from? Its definition is missing from your code. Ditto for `kd201`. It seems likely the problem is a mismatch between the data frames plotted and what you think you're plotting.

Comment: HI!! thanks for your answer, I just forgot to put it here (I wish it was something like that), I just corrected it. In fact im checking with different years from my dataset and for some it works and for some it doesnt, its really strange

Comment: Well, everything looks as far as I can tell from your code alone. If you'd like more help, please share enough sample data in a copy/pasteable format to make your question reproducible.

Comment: My only other general piece of advice would be to turn your code into a function so you aren't copy/pasting the same lines and adjusting the names of objects--which is just asking for typos.

Comment: How could I paste some part of the dataframe? Its my first post here so I dont really know.

Comment: and also, I know it would be better to make a function, but I dont know how. How could I make it to change the names? Thx

Comment: For creating a sample of your dataframe, an easy way is to do, for example `dput(head(your_data, 50))`, where your_data is your dataframe. The output would be the code you need to share the 50 first rows of said dataframe.